# Store UIButton tag value

Tags: iphone

Need to store the tag from a clicked button:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    self.selectedImage = [_images objectAtIndex:button.tag];
}
```

Works OK.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    self.selectedImage = [_images objectAtIndex:button.tag];
    self.selectedTag = button.tag;
}
```

Gives "makes pointer from integer without cast".

How should I reference button.tag correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tag` is an `NSInteger`, which is just a `typedef` for plain old `int`. Note that it is not an Object. I can't see what type your `self.selectedTag` is, but it seems to be an Object (e.g. `NSNumber`). To assign an `NSNumber` to `selectedTag`, use `self.selectedTag = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:button.tag];`

Additionally, if you use four blanks at the beginning of each line of code, StackOverflow is going to indent it and use basic syntax highlighting.

Comment: self.selectedTag is an NSInteger so that I can use it in a switch statement.